# Add active class to matching label of a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add an active class on to the matching label of a checkbox input that is outside of the parent `ul`.

I have some labels set up that are acting as buttons that have a `for=""` value that matches the ID of the checkbox, so when they're clicked they check the matching input, this is fine but what I would like to do is have a script that when the checkbox is checked or has an active class on it to add an active class to it's matching label in the `.labelBtns` section.

So far I've wrote some jQuery that console logs the `id` for the checkbox and the `for` for the matching label but I am struggling to connect the logic together to achieve what I want, so any help would be awesome.

```js
$('.m-label-inline').filter('.selected').each(function(i) {
  var idValue = $(this).find('input').attr('id');
  console.log(idValue);
  $('.sizeLabel').each(function() {
    var idValue2 = $(this).attr('for');
    console.log(idValue2);
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 50rem;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.m-refinement {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.m-label-inline {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 0.1rem solid #ddd;
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 1rem);
  margin-right: 2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  max-width: calc(50% - 1rem);
  padding: 1rem;
}

.m-label-inline:nth-child(even) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.labelBtns {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: -12em;
  margin-left: -2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.sizeLabel {
  color: #111;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  user-select: none;
}

.labelText {
  background: white;
  border: 0.2rem solid #222;
  color: #111;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 0.6rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.selected {
  background: tomato !important;
}

.selectedLabel .labelText {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="m-refinement">
  <li class="selected swatch-xs m-label-inline">
    <input class="js-refinement-link input-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="XS" name="XS" data-name="size" checked="checked" data-value="XS" title="Refine by Size: XS">
    <label for="XS">XS</label>
  </li>
  <li class=" swatch-s} m-label-inline">
    <input class="js-refinement-link input-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="S" name="S" data-value="S" title="Currently Refined by Size: S">
    <label for="S">S</label>
  </li>
  <li class="swatch-m} m-label-inline">
    <input class="js-refinement-link input-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="M" name="M" data-value="M" title="Currently Refined by Size: M">
    <label for="M">M</label>
  </li>
  <li class="swatch-l} m-label-inline">
    <input class="js-refinement-link input-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="L" name="L" data-value="L" title="Currently Refined by Size: L">
    <label for="L">L</label>
  </li>
  <li class="swatch-xl m-label-inline">
    <input class="js-refinement-link input-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="XL" name="XL" data-name="size" data-value="XL" title="Refine by Size: XL">
    <label for="XL">XL</label>
  </li>
  <li class="swatch-2xl m-label-inline">
    <input class="js-refinement-link input-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="2XL" name="2XL" data-name="size" data-value="2XL" title="Refine by Size: 2XL">
    <label for="2XL">2XL</label>
  </li>
</ul>
<section class="labelBtns">
  <label class="sizeLabel" for="XS">
    <span class="labelText">Size: XS</span>
  </label>
  <label class="sizeLabel" for="S">
    <span class="labelText">Size: S</span>
  </label>
  <label class="sizeLabel" for="M">
    <span class="labelText">Size: M</span>
  </label>
  <label class="sizeLabel" for="L">
    <span class="labelText">Size: L</span>
  </label>
  <label class="sizeLabel" for="XL">
    <span class="labelText">Size: XL</span>
  </label>
  <label class="sizeLabel" for="2XL">
    <span class="labelText ">Size: 2XL</span>
  </label>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you simply need to hook to the `change` event of the checkboxes and then set the class on the `closest()` li, depending on whether the box is checked or not. You can also use the `id` of the checkbox to find the related `label` by its `for` attribute:

Try this:

```
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('li').add('label[for="' + this.id + '"] span').toggleClass('selected', this.checked);
}).trigger('change');
```

Note that the `trigger('change')` makes the logic run when the page loads to automatically assign the class without you needing to manually put it in to the HTML.

```js
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('li').add('label[for="' + this.id + '"] span').toggleClass('selected', this.checked);
}).trigger('change');
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 50rem;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.m-refinement {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.m-label-inline {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 0.1rem solid #ddd;
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 1rem);
  margin-right: 2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  max-width: calc(50% - 1rem);
  padding: 1rem;
}

.m-label-inline:nth-child(even) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.labelBtns {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: -12em;
  margin-left: -2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.sizeLabel {
  color: #111;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  user-select: none;
}

.labelText {
  background: white;
  border: 0.2rem solid #222;
  color: #111;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 0.6rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.selected {
  background: tomato !important;
}

.selectedLabel .labelText {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="m-refinement">
  <li class="swatch-xs m-label-inline">
    <input class="js-refinement-link input-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="XS" name="XS" data-name="size" checked="checked" data-value="XS">
    <label for="XS">XS</label>
  </li>
  <li class=" swatch-s} m-label-inline">
    <input class="js-refinement-link input-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="S" name="S" data-value="S">
    <label for="S">S</label>
  </li>
  <li class="swatch-m} m-label-inline">
    <input class="js-refinement-link input-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="M" name="M" data-value="M">
    <label for="M">M</label>
  </li>
</ul>
<section class="labelBtns">
  <label class="sizeLabel" for="XS">
    <span class="labelText">Size: XS</span>
  </label>
  <label class="sizeLabel" for="S">
    <span class="labelText">Size: S</span>
  </label>
  <label class="sizeLabel" for="M">
    <span class="labelText">Size: M</span>
  </label>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi, this isn't quite what I was looking for, maybe I haven't explained it fully. When the checkbox input is checked or has a selected class on it, I want the matching label in the .labelBtns section to also have some sort of active class so if the checkbox with the id of 'XS' is checked I want a class on the matching label with the 'for="XS"' if you get me, so I can add some sort of styling to that button to show it's currently been checked and selected.

Comment: TBH Rory it was probably my explanation as it's hard to put in to words, thank you, I'll go and give this a try :)